# Changing colors of linux command line mode

Tags: linux, ubuntu, colors, centos

I've recently installed an ubuntu 10.04 server LTS and found out that it looked more attractive to me. Is there a way to get the same coloring mode on CentOS 5/6?

Also, the current `user`@`host` on Ubuntu always showing the current path without nasty brackets, I'd like to get that on CentOS too. Would that be possible?

[image: Check out the screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The appearance of the prompt is dictated by [`PS1`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Variables) shell variable. You can check the value of this variable through `echo` say `echo $PS1` on each of your machine & pick the appearance which you prefer and set the value of `PS1` as per you need. You can check [these links](http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/howtos/Bash-Prompt/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO-2.html) [for reference](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html)
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

if you type following in your CentOS, does it look ok?

```
 export PS1="\u@\h \w# "
```

(#) for root.

if yes, you could put this line in to your .bashrc

Answer (score 0):

continuing from Kent's post,

type this for PS1 variable,

> $ export PS1="\e[0;31m[\u@\h \W]\$ \e[m "

- \e[ Start color scheme
- x;y Color pair to use (x;y)
- $PS1 is your sh
- \u  username
- \h  hostname
- \W current working directory
- \e[m Stop color scheme

---

List of Color code

> Color Code
>
> Black  0;30
>
> Blue   0;34
>
> Green  0;32
>
> Red    0;31
>
> Purple    0;35
>
> Brown  0;33
>
> Blue   0;34
>
> Green  0;32
>
> Cyan   0;36
>
> Red    0;31
>
> Purple    0;35
>
> Brown  0;33

Replace digit 0 with 1 to get light color version.